# FullCalendar - Event with different 2 dates and time. Fist to Pick-UP and second Delivery Date/time

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to create an event with 2 different date/time.
I am using a system at appointment services at home. I use fullcalendar for schedule jobs.
I want to create an event with two dates, one is the date when I will make Pick Up and the second when I will Delivery the order.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for this would probably be to simply create two events and reference them to each other, You can for example create a field in your database or whatever you are using to store events, and add a "category" field, where a event can either be of category "pick-up" or "delivery". In your JS you can then use that field to determine what to do with the given event.

Additionally, you will need a field where you refer both events to each other.

LMK if you need further assistance, although I would like some more concise information, so I can fully comprehend what you are trying to do

Comment: I agree with this, what is being described in the question is simply two different events. They're not recurring events, and they're not a continuous period of time, so they're simply different events. They're certainly linked together, and having some common field value e.g. `appointmentID` to represent that would be sensible. IMO this has nothing really to do with fullCalendar specifically, despite the tag, and is just a logical problem regarding data structures.